# Json.net getter property not serialized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, json.net

I've started using json.net to produce better DateTimes, but I've noticed that one of my properties isn't being serialized. It has no setter, and its getter is reliant upon another member of the object, e.g.

```
public int AmountInPence { get; set;}
public decimal AmountInPounds { get { return (decimal)AmountInPence / 100;  } }
```

I've made a class that inherits from `JsonResult` and the main line is:

```
string serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, new IsoDateTimeConverter());
```

Can anyone tell me how to force it to serialize that property?

Edit:
Just to clarify - that was a simplified example. I've updated it to reflect that I am casting the int to decimal first. I'd forgotten to check previously, but the property is part of a partial class, because it's being returned from a WCF service. I'm declaring that property in my assembly, so could this be a clue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the Json.net. It can serialize read only properties just fine.
The problem is in your `AmountInPounds`

```
public decimal AmountInPounds { get { return AmountInPence / 100;  } }
```

Because your are doing integer division with  `/ 100` it means you will get `0` if `AmountInPence` is less than 100.

What you need is to use the [m suffix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to mark 100 as `decimal`:

```
public decimal AmountInPounds { get { return AmountInPence / 100m;  } }
```

to get the right result in `AmountInPounds`.

EDIT after comments:

The calculated property `AmountInPounds` was **in a partial class** of a WCF service's generated `DataContract`.

And in `DataContract` if a property is not marked with `DataMemberAttribute` it seems it won't be serialized.

So beside the OP's answer:

```
[JsonPropertyAttribute(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include)]
public decimal AmountInPounds { get { return (decimal)AmountInPence / 100;  } }
```

This is also works:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public decimal AmountInPounds { get { return (decimal)AmountInPence / 100; } }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think it's because of that though (I've edited my question)

Comment: Ok, then you should provide more context. What is `Data` what your are trying to serialize? What is the output? Because as @StriplingWarrior also pointed out: JsonConvert serializes `AmountInPounds`...

Comment: Data is an object - a property of JsonResult. Would it have to be cast first?

Comment: No you don't need to cast. I think the problem is with the partial class... could you post a simplified but reproduce able code? With partials correct namespaces etc. Because it should also work with partials...

Comment: By the way in your edit the part `I'm declaring that property in my assembly` is a little bit confusing, because you know that partial classes cannot be distributed into multiple assemblies...

Comment: Sorry, I just meant that it's not being set by the WCF service and this is the only other assembly that uses it.

Comment: Just realised I can't use that attribute on a readonly property like that: it needs to be [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public decimal AmountInPounds { get { return (decimal)AmountInPence / 100; } internal set { } }
which is a bit of a hack. Can you update your answer please?

Comment: This also fixed my similar issue with WebAPI/Json.Net. Thanks!

Comment: Necroing to clarify:
"It can serialize read only properties just fine"

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm
Because a JsonConverter creates a new value, a converter will not work with readonly properties because there is no way to assign the new value to the property. Either change the property to have a public setter or place a JsonPropertyAttribute or DataMemberAttribute on the property.

Answer (score 3):

OK looks like I've found the answer, sorry for not providing more details in the post, but I don't think it mattered in the end.

I needed to add an attribute on the AmountInPounds property:

```
[JsonPropertyAttribute(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include)]
public decimal AmountInPounds { get { return (decimal)AmountInPence / 100;  } }
```

Comment: I'm glad that you've found a solution, but it's still very strange. Because I was not able to reproduce your issue not with partial classes or inheritance or with nullable properties. `Newtonsoft.Json version 4.0.8` always included the readonly properties...

Comment: Yes, I created a seperate solution replicating everything apart from the class being created by WCF service and it worked as expected. Perhaps there's an attribute on that class that prevents Json.Net from automatically serializing those readonly properties. Thanks for your time!

Comment: It seems the `DataMemberAttribute` also solves your problem, I don't know why maybe this is a bug in Json.net. However I've also updated my answer with this info.

Comment: Perhaps because there were attributes on the class that the standard JavaScriptSerializer used, it wasn't needed on the property, but if Json.Net doesn't use them then that's the reason it stopped working. Anyhoo I've marked your answer as accepted