# How to serialize enclosing object properties in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I am following the official [ASP.NET Core 2.2 paging example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.2#add-paging-to-students-index) over at Microsoft.

Here, I'm adding a `PaginatedList.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace BlatantlyCopiedCode
{
    public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

        public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            PageIndex = pageIndex;
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

            this.AddRange(items);
        }

        public bool HasPreviousPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex > 1);
            }
        }

        public bool HasNextPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
            return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
    }
}
```

and adding this to my EF object `Merge`

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<PaginatedList<Merge>> Index(int? pageNumber)
{
    var merges = context.Merges;

    int pageSize = 20;
    return await PaginatedList<Merge>.CreateAsync(merges.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize);
}
```

When the result is serialized to JSON in the controller, the properties from `PaginatedList<T>` aren't serialized, only the `List<Merge>`. How can I force the properties from `PaginatedList<T>` to appear in the resulting JSON?

Comment: I think this will help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727836/json-net-getter-property-not-serialized

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Amy, although I'm not exactly sure I understand what you mean. Decorating the properties with `[JsonPropertyAttribute(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include)]` does not seem to do the trick, at least.

Comment: Okay, that's what I had in mind, but I wasn't sure if that was the issue.

Comment: I think `PaginatedList` is just handled by serializer as an ordinary `List`, resulting in a json-array. Note that, in the docs, it wasn't supposed to be serialized into json. As a solution, I'd prefer just decorating a list rather than deriving from it. So it would be json object with a couple of fields for paging and the array itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that it inherits the `List<T>` which constrains the result to a list.Modify your code to below

```
public class PaginatedList<T> //: List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public List<T> Items { get; set; }

    public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

        this.Items = new List<T>();
        this.Items.AddRange(items);
    }
    //...
 }
```

Comment: Could simplify the last portion to `Items = items.ToList()`, assuming you needed a copy.

Comment: Awesome, that does it! A little digging reveals that this behaviour in fact is by design: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11368028/182048.